# Where does Swagger/OpenAPI place documentation?

Tags: python, swagger, openapi

I just downloaded a Swagger/OpenAPI generated SDK. I know that API documentation should have been autogenerated by Swagger itself... however I am looking through the file directory and don't see anything. I have tried searching on this topic for a few hours now and nothing has been very helpful. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI is a standard of defining an API, it is not itself a tool that generates SDKs or documentation.

You likely used [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) or a similar tool to generate your SDK - documentation would need to be generated from another tool, such as [ReDoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc) or something from [SmartBear](https://swagger.io/resources/articles/documenting-apis-with-swagger/#how-to-generate-openapi-from-existing-apis-7) (the original authors of Swagger).